# How do I change my StackExchange password?

Tags: support

How do I change my Stack Exchange password, without removing the [image]Google acount?

Only option is remove the Google account!

The reason I ask this is that Google Chrome & Chromium are disreguarding the Gnome Keyring, which means I have to login when I start a google browser  when I open a SE forum like AskUbuntu, and again when I have to relogin after blanking the screen (away for > 10 min) and then wait for my Google pin-code (or run around looking for my phone)
Thats a whole lot of loging in all the time!!

Answer (score 7):

If you are logged in with the Google account, you change the password for the Google account to change the password you authenticate with on StackExchange for - you wouldn't have to adjust anything for the StackExchange 'password' since it relies on you successfully authenticating to Google to logon (effectively, there is no StackExchange password for you because of this).

The login is brokered by the OpenID and Google Accounts authentication provider system.  To change your StackExchange 'password', you would change your Google password, as your Google account is used for the login authentication.  If you don't need or want to change the Google password, then you don't need to worry about the StackExchange "password" because it looks like your account was created with the Google Account credentials.

The exception would be if you registered with just email and password rather than using some other auth mechanism (such as Google, or OpenID) to login with.  Looking at your history, I don't see that to be the case, because the credential was added automatically because you logged in with Google to the site.

If you wish to authenticate with something other than Google, use the "Add more logins" button to add additional logon credentials, as was indicated by [terdon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) in the comments here.

Comment: OK what happens if I remove my Google account?

And how do I login without logging in to Google first?

Comment: @KenMollerup you chose to log in with Google when you first created your SE account. This means you don't have an SE password but instead always authenticate through Google. If you no longer want to authenticate that way, you can click on the "add more logins" button in your screenshot.

Comment: @terdon I did originally sign up with a password, but either I can't remember it, or the original email don't work anymore!  Do you know what happens if I remove Google?

Comment: The screenshot you show suggests you don't have any other accounts. So if you created one with a password you've since deleted it or it was for another SE site or something. I would recommend you first add a new, google-free  login  and *then* delete your Google credentials. That way you don't risk being locked out.

Comment: @terdon good suggestion.